# Passing/returning a class with type parameter to a function

Tags: java, generics

Let's assume the following method (say from Guava's Iterables):

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> filter(final Iterable<?> unfiltered, final Class<T> type) {
    return null;
}
```

and this collection:

```
Set<?> objs = ...;
```

then the following code compiles and the generics are correctly derived

```
Iterable<String> a2 = Iterables.filter(objs, String.class);
```

(In Guava this would return an iterable of all Strings in `objs`.)

But now lets assume the following class:

```
static class Abc<E> {
    E someField;
}
```

I have no idea how to call `filter` and get `Iterable<Abc<?>>`:

```
Iterable<Abc>    a3 = Iterables.filter(objs, Abc.class);
Iterable<Abc<?>> a4 = Iterables.filter(objs, Abc.class); // Compile error - Abc and Abc<?> are incompatible types
Iterable<Abc<?>> a5 = Iterables.filter(objs, Abc<?>.class); // Compile error
Iterable<Abc<?>> a6 = Iterables.<Abc<?>>filter(objs, Abc.class); // Compile error
Iterable<Abc<?>> a7 = (Iterable<Abc<?>>) Iterables.filter(objs, Abc.class); //  Compile error - inconvertible types
Iterable<Abc<?>> a8 = Iterables.filter(objs, new Abc<?>().getClass()); // Compile error
Iterable<Abc<?>> a8a = Iterables.filter(objs, new Abc<Object>().getClass()); // Compile error
```

Only a3 compiles, but then I do not have the parameter on Abc, and thus no generic type checking in subsequent code is done.

I know that the type parameters are not present at runtime and so I do not atempt to write code like:

```
Iterable<Abc<String>> a9 = Iterables.filter(objs, Abc<String>.class); // Compile error
```

I just want to filter all objects of the type Abc (as a3 does) but having the generic parameter in the result. The only way of doing this I found is the following, which is silly:

```
Iterable<Abc<?>> a10 = new HashSet<Abc<?>>();
for (Abc<?> a : Iterables.filter(objs, Abc.class)) {
    ((Set<Abc<?>>)a10).add(a);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no satisfactory answer to this question. Class literals for types parameterized with *unbounded wildcards only* would work out in theory, we just don't have them.

You can produce the `Class<Abc<?>>`-typed class object with an unchecked cast and move it to a utility method or field. As long as there are few `Abc`s, this works quite nicely.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Class<Abc<?>> ABC = (Class<Abc<?>>)(Object) Abc.class;
```

Comment: I see, but that means, I can also either of the following:
    `Iterable<Abc<?>> a1 = Iterables.filter(this.getObjects(), (Class<Abc<?>>)(Object)Abc.class);`
    `Iterable<Abc<?>> a2 = (Iterable<Abc<?>>)(Object) Iterables.filter(this.getObjects(), Abc.class);`
It is ugly but it works.

Comment: @Jirka-x1 Yes, inlining works just as well. The only downside is that suppressing the warning is less local.

Answer (score 0):

I found this compiles..

```
public static <T> Iterable<Abc<T>> myFilter (Iterable<Abc<T>> myIterator) {
    Class<Abc<T>> myClass = null;
    Iterable<Abc<T>> a3 = Iterables.filter(myIterator, myClass); 
    return a3;
}
```

But it just moves the same problem up to the caller of **myFilter()**. I suspect [Ben Schulz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774444/ben-schulz) has the correct answer.

Comment: It compiles, but the `myclass` variable has no content. But I can use the method Ben suggested: `(Abc<?>)(Object) Abc.class` to assign it.