# How can I cast generic type to generic type with generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method in one of my utility classes that takes a collection and a class object, and returns an Iterable instance that can iterate over all members of the collection that are instances of the specified class.  Its signature is:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> iterable (
      Iterable<? super T> source, Class<T> requiredClass);
```

This works very well for most use cases, but now I need to use it with a generic class, `Item<PROTOTYPE>`.  I understand that I cannot be certain that the items returned by the resulting iterator cannot be guaranteed to have any particular prototype, so I tried to cast its return as follows:

```
Iterable<Item<?>> allItems = (Iterable<Item<?>>) 
                            TypeCheckingIterator.iterable(source, Item.class);
```

Unfortunately this returns a compiler error "Cannot cast from `Iterable<Item>` to `Iterable<Item<?>>`"

Why can it not perform this cast when I can cast `Item` to `Item<?>` quite happily? Is there a way I can force it to make this cast, without having to cast the items returned by the iterators explicitly?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10869467/774444

Comment: @LouisWasserman Which suffers the exact same problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use type erasure if you are sure its safe

```
Iterable<Item<?>> allItems = (Iterable<Item<?>>) (Iterable)
                        TypeCheckingIterator.iterable(source, Item.class);
```

or

```
Iterable<Item<?>> allItems =
                     TypeCheckingIterator.<Item<?>>iterable(source, Item.class);
```

Comment: I can't get your second solution to work.  I get the error: The parameterized method <Item<?>>iterable(Iterable<? super<Item<?>>, Class<Item<?>>) of type TypeCheckingIterator is not applicable for the arguments (Iterable<PositionedObject>, Class<Item>).  Not sure what the issue is, PositionedObject is definitely a superclass of Item<?>

Comment: And changing the casts in the first solution to (Iterable<Item<?>>)(Iterable<?>) avoids a raw type warning.

Comment: Its not that all `Item<?>` are equal. I would try to introduce the `<?>` wildcard as I don't see how it helps you.

Comment: You can use `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")`  There are some casts, the compiler cannot determine is safe.